# How to upload multiple artifacts(.zip) to different targets in arifactory using Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

How to upload multiple maven artifacts(.zip) to different targets in Jfrog Artifactory using Jenkins pipeline script

Answer (score 2):

If your using the Jenkins artifactory plugin, this grants access to the Jfrog Cli which enables use of uploadSpec and downloadSpec. (Artifactory.server name is configured under jenkins global settings after installing artifactory plugin)

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'
def uploadSpec = """{
                     "files": [
                                {
                                "pattern": "*-file-1.zip",
                                "target": "location1/1"
                                },
                                {
                                "pattern": "*-file-2.zip",
                                "target": "location2/2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }"""
def buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)
```

More info on filespecs available on their website https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven `deploy:deploy-file` goal (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) to upload arbitrary files.

Comment: It looks something like below                                                                                 def uploadSpec = """{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
      "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/"
    }
 ]
}"""
server.upload(uploadSpec)

Comment: What "looks something like below"?